# -replace does not replace string with "()"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace a string containing parentheses in PowerShell. However, when I try this to do this it is not working.

Any idea as to where I'm going wrong? What am I suppose to do to replace a string containing `()` with `-replace` in PowerShell?

```
$a='Some Text with (round) brackets. This text is long.'
$ch="with (round) brackets."
$b="this text"
$a -replace $ch,$b
```

**Output:**

```
Some Text with (round) brackets. This text is long.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-replace` useses *regular expression* so you have to to *escape* your `regex`:

```
$a='Some Text with (round) brackets. This text is long.'
$ch="with (round) brackets."
$b="this text"
$a -replace [regex]::Escape($ch),$b
```

**Output:**

```
Some Text this text This text is long.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi again! Any idea how I can also deal with $a="Some Text with `round` brackets. This text is long."

Answer (score 3):

Add Escape Character `\` to the string:

```
$ch="with \(round\) brackets."
$b="this text"
$a -replace $ch,$b

Some Text this text This text is long.
```

Or use

```
[Regex]::Escape($ch),$b
```